# How to group rectangles returned by cascade classifier in OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to group rectangle returned by a cv2.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale()

The cascade in this case is for eye detection and the function returns many overlapping rectangles for a single eye. How can i group these overlapping rectangles.

```
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/k00lk0der1/opencv-2.4.9/data/haarcascade/haarcascade_eye.xml')
eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roiep_gblur)
for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
    #processing here
```

I want to group the overlapping rectangles in eyes and store them in a new object named eyel so that code appears as follows

```
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/k00lk0der1/opencv-2.4.9/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml')
eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roiep_gblur)
eyel = # code for grouping rectangles in eyes
for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyel:
    #processing here for grouped rectangles
```

`

Comment: Did you try http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#grouprectangles

Comment: @Micka It gives an error

Comment: can you post the error message?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "show11.py", line 33, in <module>
    for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyel:
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
`

Comment: not sure about python errors, maybe there is no eye detected so the  groupRectangles call crashes? can you catch that by an if-statement?

Comment: ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack –  this means that you have nothing to unpack, i.e. your array **eyel** is empty. This means that no detections were returned by the cascade. Maybe you gave it the wrong path when you called cv2.CascadeClassifier.